# makefile define equivalent in Scons

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, scons

In a gcc makefile, you can use the -D flag to specify a define in the compiled program. For example, instead of putting #define SOMETHING, you can specify -DSOMETHING in the makefile. What is the equivalent of this in SCons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want the `CPPDEFINES` construction variable. See [the SCons documentation page](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/a5025.html) for some more details, under `CPPDEFINES`.